# Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'fundTypes' of undefined

Tags: angular

fund-dropdown.js

```
export class FundDropdown{
  fundTypes: string[];
  fundCategorys: string[];
}
```

test.component.ts

```
 export class PrimengTestComponent implements OnInit {
  date: Date;
  fundDropdown: FundDropdown;

  constructor(private fundInfoService: FundInfoService) {
    console.log(this.fundDropdown);
    console.log(this.fundDropdown.fundTypes.length);//the error occurs in this line
 }
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fundDropdown = new FundDropdown();
    this.fundInfoService.getFundTypeAndFundCategory().subscribe(
      (data) => {
        console.log(data);
        this.fundDropdown = data;
      },
      (error) => console.log(error)
    );
  }
}
```

the data of fundDropdown is :

```
{"fundCategorys":["aaaa"],"fundTypes":["sdf","qwe","agas"]}
```

the fundDropdown data is from the background, its type is Map<String, List>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `fundDropdown` is undefined here, so there is no value of `fundTypes` on `fundDropdown` as of now.

You must declare an empty object of type `FundDropdown` like below.

```
fundDropdown = <FundDropdown>{};
```

By doing so, you are accessible to -

```
this.fundDropdown.fundTypes
```

still, you can't use `length` property on it because array `fundTypes` is not declared as empty array yet.

So you should put this console in the method `this.fundInfoService.getFundTypeAndFundCategory().subscribe(...` as data is coming dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor the `fundDropdown` is undefined.

As you mentioned the data is coming from backend, and you dont know when will it arrive, but until the response the `fundDropdown` will be undefined.

In the other hand the `constructor` will be fired first, so it is impossible to receive data faster from `ngOnInit`. You can learn more about them if you searching for Angular lifecycles.

[Angular lifecycles](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#hooking-into-the-component-lifecycle)

Comment: To improve your answer, you could provide a good link about Angular lifecycles. Also, consider using the backticks for inline code formatting, as in `fundDropdown`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. In my future responses i will try to pay more attention for these.